# Get indexs and columns from a Dataframe that satisfy two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new in Python and Pandas.

I'm trying to filter a string dataframe by two conditions, to get a list or dataframe with indexs and columns that satisfy both conditions. I get this dataframe from a spreadsheet where each cell is YES or NOT.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO'], ['NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO'], ['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], ['YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES']],

     index=['task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4'],

     columns=['David', 'Carol', 'Tony', 'Anna'])
```

df

```
            David   Carol   Tony   Anna
taks1       YES     YES     NO     NO
task2       NO      YES     NO     NO
task3       NO      NO      NO     NO
task4       YES     NO      NO     YES
```

I need to get something like this (two lists, dataframe, bidimensional array...):

```
David   task1
David   task4
Carol   task1
Carol   task2
Anna    task4
```

I have used loc, but I cannot extend the filter for all the columns:

```
active = df.loc[lambda df1: df1['David'] == 'YES', :]
```

Rows and columns number are unknown when I read spreadsheet, therefore, I need to have a flexible solution for different tables size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas' `melt` to convert the data frame to the long format, and then apply the condition

```
df_long = df.melt(value_vars=['David', 'Carol', 'Tony', 'Anna'], ignore_index=False).reset_index()
df_long.columns = ['Task', 'Name', 'Value']
print(df_long)
     Task   Name Value
0   task1  David   YES
1   task2  David    NO
2   task3  David    NO
3   task4  David   YES
4   task1  Carol   YES
5   task2  Carol   YES
6   task3  Carol    NO
7   task4  Carol    NO
8   task1   Tony    NO
9   task2   Tony    NO
10  task3   Tony    NO
11  task4   Tony    NO
12  task1   Anna    NO
13  task2   Anna    NO
14  task3   Anna    NO
15  task4   Anna   YES
         
df_long.loc[df_long['Value']=='YES', ['Name', 'Task']].reset_index(drop=True)
    Name   Task
0  David  task1
1  David  task4
2  Carol  task1
3  Carol  task2
4   Anna  task4
```

Answer (score 1):

> need to get something like this (two lists, dataframe, bidimensional array...):

Then how about

```
[*zip(*df[df == "YES"].stack().index)]
```

which gives

```
[('task1', 'task1', 'task2', 'task4', 'task4'),
 ('David', 'Carol', 'Carol', 'David', 'Anna')]
```

We get the entries that are `YES` and then `stack` the columns (names) next to the index (tasks). Since we are only interested in index, take `.index`. Then some `zip`ping turns the multiindex into two separate lists.

(If you want it sorted by names, then you can put in `.sort_index(level=1)` after `.stack()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your df is pivoted, thus you want to unpivot your table. Unpivoting can be achieved using `.melt()` in pandas. Here's the full code.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'task'})
>>> print(df)
    task David Carol Tony Anna
0  taks1   YES   YES   NO   NO
1  task2    NO   YES   NO   NO
2  task3    NO    NO   NO   NO
3  task4   YES    NO   NO  YES
>>> df = df.melt(['task'])
>>> print(df.loc[df['value']=='YES', ['variable', 'task']])
   variable   task
0     David  taks1
3     David  task4
4     Carol  taks1
5     Carol  task2
15     Anna  task4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `melt` and then `query` to filter the result -

```
result = df.melt(value_vars=['David', 'Carol', 'Tony', 'Anna'], ignore_index=False).query('value == "YES"')['variable']
```

**Output -**

```
task1    David
task4    David
task1    Carol
task2    Carol
task4     Anna
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df.unstack().eq('YES')
```

Based on requirement:

**Multiindex array**

```
s[s].index

MultiIndex([('David', 'task1'),
            ('David', 'task4'),
            ('Carol', 'task1'),
            ('Carol', 'task2'),
            ( 'Anna', 'task4')],
           )
```

**List**

```
s[s].index.to_list()

[('David', 'task1'),
 ('David', 'task4'),
 ('Carol', 'task1'),
 ('Carol', 'task2'),
 ('Anna', 'task4')]
```

**Numpy array**

```
s[s].index.to_numpy()

array([('David', 'task1'), ('David', 'task4'), ('Carol', 'task1'),
       ('Carol', 'task2'), ('Anna', 'task4')], dtype=object)
```

**DataFrame**

```
s[s].index.to_frame()
                0       1
David   task1   David   task1
        task4   David   task4
Carol   task1   Carol   task1
        task2   Carol   task2
Anna    task4   Anna    task4
```

**Proper Dataframe with column names**

We are using `unstack` and then fetching the rows with 'YES'.   After that, all the effort is to get the output in desired format.

**Code**

```
df.unstack().eq('YES').to_frame().rename(columns={
    (0):'val'}).query('val == True').reset_index().rename(
    columns={'level_0':'index', 'level_1':'value'}).drop('val',1)
```

**Output**

```
    index   value
0   David   task1
1   David   task4
2   Carol   task1
3   Carol   task2
4   Anna    task4
```